# Folder structure of message access profile(MAP) in android kitkat version

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-4.4-kitkat

I have started working on message access profile(MAP) in bluetooth. I have created APIs required on client side device to communicate through MAP. I am using Android kitkat versioned phone as the MAP server since MAP support is provided in kitkat version.

But while using setfolder api from client device, i have no idea where the folder is setting in the server device.
By using listfolder api from client device to server device through MAP, i have got only "telecom" folder as the response.

Can anyone explain about the exact MAP folder structure in android phones

Answer (score 3):

You can check in spec: https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/MAP.aspx

As per the folder structure mentioned in spec, its mandatory to support below folders with user defined folders:
/telecom
/telecom/msg;
/telecom/msg/inbox;
/telecom/msg/sent;
/telecom/msg/deleted;
/telecom/msg/outbox;
/telecom/msg/draft